# how to verify shadowroot text with robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I have to verify following shadow-root text using robot framework keyword. I tried with `Page should contain` but it didn't work.

I also tried with following in console to locate its text, but it is displaying null.
`document.querySelector("div").shadowroot`

```
<div class="jss3737">
  <div class="jss3770"> .. </div>
  <div class="jss3801">
    #shadow-root (open)
     "you can list the following elements in the field"
  </div>
```

Can you please suggest any way to read/verify/capture the text in shadowroot.

Comment: Can you add a full example, or refer to the example you're following. Presently it's not possible to retrace your steps and get a similar result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assigned temporary id (yk_temp) to the shadowroot parent tag, then used following command.

```
Execute Javascript     return document.getElementById("yk_temp").shadowRoot.innerHTML
```